# linking G Suite and Windows Domain Controller for user management

Tags: active-directory, ldap, authentication, domain-controller, g-suite

I manage a small business and use G Suite for user management of all google apps as well as authentication for as many third party services as possible (like slack, atlassin and so on).

Then we also have an intranet with internally hosted services where I use a Windows Server Domain Controller with AD to manage users and use LDAP to authenticate users on all the internally hosted services in the intranet.

So currently I have to manage all user profiles twice, once for the intranet through the windows DC and once for all the cloud services we use through G Suite.

Now afaik G Suite can't act as a DC, so it can't replace AD. But I wonder whether there's a way to link our local DC with G Suite to sync accounts and permissions. Optimally I'd manage all the user accounts only through G Suite.

Is there some way to do this?

If not, what's the best way to have only a single user account which can be used for internal services as well as for various cloud subscriptions?

Answer (score 2):

There is [Google Cloud Directory Sync](https://support.google.com/a/answer/106368?hl=en) (actually the first Google result for `gsuite ad sync`!):

> With Google Cloud Directory Sync (GCDS), you can synchronize the data
>   in your Google domain with your Microsoft® Active Directory® or LDAP
>   server. Your Google users, groups, and shared contacts are
>   synchronized to match the information in your LDAP server.

However, this synchronizes from AD to G Suite, so you'd have to manage your G Suite users through AD, not the other way around.